# What exact time of the day does the Golden vendor in Cyrodiil appear?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

What **exact time on Friday** does the Golden vendor appear in Cyrodiil?

This is another surprisingly difficult answer to find on the Internet. I have only found rough estimates with no indication of the time zone of the author giving the rough estimate.

In answering, use whatever time zone you’re comfortable with. If mine is different, I’ll convert.

I know it is Friday some time. 6 AM US Central Time is too early, but she appears at least by 8:30 PM US Central Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8 pm est is the designated time.  It has shown up late if you log off and log back in it usually arrives on time.  Daylight saving times do change the spawn times!